# Set magento deployment mode to production fails

Tags: magento2, command-line

I've installed a new Magento 2 installation with [Softaculous](https://www.softaculous.com/) on my hostingserver. After installation I would change the default deployment mode to production but I have the following error (using SSH):

```
foo@en07-phx [~/public_html/m2test/bin]# php magento deploy:mode:show
    Current application mode: default.
foo@en07-phx [~/public_html/m2test/bin]# php magento deploy:mode:set production
    Enabled maintenance mode
    Static content deployment start
    Command returned non-zero exit code:
    `php -f /home/foo/public_html/m2test/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US 2>&1`
```

Anyone knows what could be wrong? Because I'm using v2.0.0.0, this might be fixed already in a newer version on Github but I'm not able to install that using softaculous and I have no clue on how to use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) from my [hostingprovider](https://forums.stablehost.com/index.php?threads/using-composer.748/).

**Edit1**:
Following the suggestion of @Silvan (by running the command seperately), I get the following output:

```
=== frontend -> Magento/blank -> en_US ===
Successful: 1965 files; errors: 0
=== frontend -> Magento/luma -> en_US ===
Successful: 1965 files; errors: 0
=== adminhtml -> Magento/backend -> en_US ===
Successful: 1843 files; errors: 0
=== Minify templates ===
Successful: 845 files modified
```

**Edit2**:
This is independent of Softaculous installer because I have the same problem with a manual installation of the latest github code as of today (2016/01/12).

**Edit3**:
Raised a github issue. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2972

Comment: Have you set file permissions as recommended? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html

Comment: This output looks normal.

Comment: @SteveJohnson The output "Command returned non-zero exit code"? Or the single test output. I got the deployment statement running without problems on my local machine and the end output of a successful deployment is way different.

Comment: The test output looks normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the php memory limit to 512M solved the issue.

Comment: It is better if you set memory limit temporarily instead of change setting in php.ini.

Try `php -dmemory_limit=1G namespace:command`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something goes wrong in the statement:

```
php -f /home/foo/public_html/m2test/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US 2>&1
```

The real error is not shown (Command returned non-zero exit code). Try to execute that statement manually to see what the real error is:

```
php -f /home/foo/public_html/m2test/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```

Comment: See my updated answer for results

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue trying to change back to production mode.

It turned out to be because I had multiple versions of php available and where apache was configured to use v7 and I had been prefixing other commands with the correct path the magento deploy used the system version. Setting the correct path in the environment variable fixed the issue.